# Confluence Error 500 while setup

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, debian, confluence

I've got an Error 500 while trying to setup Confluence saying the **bean** i18NBean **was not found**.

I'am running a debian Jessie and I try to install confluence in a docker container following this [turotial](https://cptactionhank.github.io/docker-atlassian-confluence/)

This error occurs always when I hit the "database setup step" while confluence trys to setup the database. The weird thing is, this happens also when I try to use the embedded database...

Comment: post some more info like the .yml, the `docker run`, the Dockerfile because we can't guess

Comment: I'am running the ''docker run' commands and using the Dockerfile from the 'tutorial' I've posted. I did not change anything of that.

here is a link to the dockerfile:
https://github.com/cptactionhank/docker-atlassian-confluence/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Can you please check docker logs confluence and let us know what's in the log?